# mysql is not reading the .mylogin.cfg file correctly

Tags: mysql, database-administration, percona

I have created the .mylogin.cfg file with below commands and then tried to connect to mysql with the --login-path option but unable to connect to it. any suggestion are really useful.

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=test --host=10.219.39.121  --user=vidya --password 
mysql_config_editor print --all
[test]
user = vidya
password = *****
host = 10.219.39.121
```

while connecting it is showing error on different IP address as shown below

```
mysql --login-path=test
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'vidya'@'10.219.39.122' (using password: YES)
```

Here my concern is why it is showing different IP address and why it is not able to connect even the password is correct. **I am using mysql 5.6.6-m9-alpha60.1-log Percona Server.**